# Convergent and Divergent of $x^{n}\sin(nx)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to check does this series converge?

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }x^{n}\sin(nx)$.

So I have decomposed it to 2 cases :

1) If $|x|<1$:

$0\leq |x^{n}\sin(nx)|\leq |x^{n}|$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }x^{n}$ - converges so  $|x^{n}\sin(nx)|$ also converges $\Rightarrow $ $x^{n}\sin(nx)$ converges.

2) If $|x|\geq 1$:
 $x^{n}\sin(nx)\not \rightarrow 0$ $\Rightarrow $ series diverges.

But what happens if $ x=\pi k$? Does it converge?

Comment: $x=k\pi$, then the series is 0

Comment: you may think the points $x=k\pi$ rather than just $|x|<=>1$

Answer (score 3):

Your proof to $|x|\ge 1$ the series diverges is not complete.

Suppose $|x|\ge 1$,

- If $x=k\pi $, the series is zero, obviously converges.
- If $x=q\pi$ with $q\in \mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Z}$, then you may find a subsequence of $\sin nx=\mathrm{const}\neq 0$, thus the series diverges.
- If $x=q\pi$ with $q$ irrational, then for any $\delta >0$, you may find infinitle many $n$ such that $|\frac{nx}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}|<\delta $, thus the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n \sin(nx) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{Imag}(x^n e^{inx}) = \text{Imag} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(x e^{ix} \right)^n \right)$$

Comment: Why not $\Im$? ${}{}{}$